# How do I install LXDE offline into debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am running the latest version of Debian, **command line only**. the PC is **offline**. Do not ask me to get it online because i can't.

I want to install the desktop environment LXDE but I have no CD and no internet for the machine. Where and how can I get LXDE (or any other DE) for the gnome console and install it from a flashdrive or other removable media such as an external hardrive? Is there a package installer for this that I can just move off of the flashdrive and install it?

There has been near to nothing on the internet that tells me how to do this. all of the responses have been the "apt-get" which I have to be online to use right?

Comment: I think that the debian install iso contains the required packages. If you can get a copy of the install iso and change your apt.list to include the dvd it may work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apt-offline`:

```
Package: apt-offline
Maintainer: Ritesh Raj Sarraf <rrs@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Depends: python, python:any (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~), python-argparse,
         apt, less, python-magic
Recommends: python-soappy, debian-archive-keyring, python-lzma
Description-en: offline APT package manager
 apt-offline is an Offline APT Package Manager.
 .
 apt-offline can fully update and upgrade an APT based distribution without
 connecting to the network, all of it transparent to APT.
 .
 apt-offline can be used to generate a signature on a machine (with no network).
 This signature contains all download information required for the APT database
 system. This signature file can be used on another machine connected to the
 internet (which need not be a Debian box and can even be running windows) to
 download the updates.
 The downloaded data will contain all updates in a format understood by APT and
 this data can be used by apt-offline to update the non-networked machine.
 .
 apt-offline can also fetch bug reports and make them available offline.
Homepage: http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org
```

You'll need to manually download and copy to a USB stick or CD or something the `apt-offline` package and all its dependencies (that aren't already installed) first, but once you've done that and installed them with `dpkg`, you can then use `apt-offline` to install and upgrade other packages.